# How to open a jQuery Mobile popup programmatically and close it after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I want to open a jQuery Mobile popup programmatically and then close it after some seconds, here is my code :

is there anything wrong, cause I'm not getting what I want to show

```js
$( "#p" ).popup( "open" ); 
setTimeout( function(){ $( "#p" ).popup( "close" ); }, 5000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<div data-role="popup" id="p" data-position-to="window" data-transition="turn"><p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/genius50/m3kkpLtj/)

Comment: You have a syntax error in your closing p tag. Change it to </p>.  http://jsfiddle.net/m3kkpLtj/2/

Comment: Thanks, but same problem, it's no showing the popup for 5 seconds

Comment: Check the fiddle link again. I accidentally showed the old one.

Comment: doesn't work my friend

Comment: Sorry, try this one http://jsfiddle.net/m3kkpLtj/4/

Comment: Always the same thing my friend

Comment: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-Windows/doc/4-0-alertbox/  something like this?  (it's just a wrapper to pretty much what you are doing)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure your code is within a page event handler like pagecreate so that jQM has initialized the popup widget:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <button id="btnpopup">Show Dynamic Popup</button>
    </div> 

    <div data-role="popup" id="p" data-position-to="window" data-transition="turn"><p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p></div>
</div>  

$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 
    $("#btnpopup").on("click", function(){
        $("#p").popup("open"); 
        setTimeout(function(){  $("#p").popup("close"); }, 5000);
    });
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/mxta9L5b/)**

Answer (score 8):

it is actually simple:

```
 $("#chatWindow").popup("open");
```